# Tunnel only one program (UDP & TCP) through another server

Tags: openvpn, udp, tunnel, socks

I have a windows machine at home and a server with debian installed.
I want to tunnel the UDP traffic from one (any only this) program on my windows machine through my server.

For tcp traffic this was easy using putty as a socks5 proxy and then connecting via ssh to my server - but this does not seem to work for UDP.
Then I setup dante as a socks5 proxy but it seems to create a new instance/thread per connection which leads to a huge ram usage for my server, so this was no option either.

So most people recommend openvpn, so my question: Can I use openvpn to just tunnel this one program through my server? Is there a way to maybe create a local socks5 proxy on my windows machine and set it as a proxy in my program and only this proxy then will use openvpn?

Thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 2):

Socks5 will not work for UDP packets. So you can setup an openvpn and just put everything through there. If you want something for just one program, you could try [ctunnel](http://nardcore.org/ctunnel/).

Comment: How can I start a new line here? Every time I hit ENTER it saves my post? So I installed it on my server and my windows machine. On the client machine I entered ctunnel -H 199.x.x.x -c -l 802 -f 801 -C aes-256-cfb    But what should happen now? There is nothing listening on port 802 on my pc afterwards.